Azure AI Foundry deployed promptflow providing different responses in compute session chat and endpoint API call
I'm trying to make a customer support chatbot using Azure AI Studio/Foundry. I created a promptflow using the chatplayground and deployed it. When testing out the model in the chat function of the promptflow compute session, the response to a query is as expected, with the model responding in the expected format with relevant indexed data. However, when I call the endpoint of the deployed promptflow and send it the same query, the response is is not as expected and is in the correct format but does not provided relevant indexed data as part of its response and instead asks the user for more details regarding their inquiry.
I tested it multiple times with the same query as well as others and the responses are different to varying degrees every time.
Here's C# code I used to call the deployed endpoint of the promptflow:
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{


    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {apiKey}");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("azureml-model-deployment", modelDeploymentName);



    var requestBody = new
    {
        chat_history = chatHistory,
        question = prompt
    };

    string jsonRequestBody = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestBody);

    var response = await client.PostAsync(
        endpointUrl,
        new StringContent(jsonRequestBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
    );

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {

        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
    else
    {

        string errorMessage = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        throw new Exception($"Error: {response.StatusCode}, Details: {errorMessage}");
    }
}

I'm fairly sure that I'm calling the API correctly since it provides a response, just not the expected one. Would anyone have any idea what might be causing the disparity in the promptflows responses to the same query between calling its endpoint and chatting with it in the compute session directly?

could please the which packages you are using and what documents you are following?

Below is the code to send a request to a custom PromptFlow endpoint hosted in Azure, allowing interaction with an AI model deployment.
 var chatHistory = new[]
        {
            new { role = "system", content = "You are a helpful customer support chatbot." },
            new { role = "user", content = "Hi, I need help with my subscription." },
            new { role = "assistant", content = "Sure, can you provide more details about the issue?" }
        };

        var prompt = "What are the steps to cancel my subscription?";
        var requestBody = new
        {
            chat_history = chatHistory,
            question = prompt
        };

        string jsonRequestBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestBody);

        try
        {
            var response = await CallPromptFlowEndpoint(jsonRequestBody);
            Console.WriteLine("API Response:");
            Console.WriteLine(response);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    private static async Task<string> CallPromptFlowEndpoint(string jsonRequestBody)
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {ApiKey}");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("azureml-model-deployment", ModelDeploymentName);
            var response = await client.PostAsync(
                EndpointUrl,
                new StringContent(jsonRequestBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
            );

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                string errorMessage = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                throw new Exception($"Error: {response.StatusCode}, Details: {errorMessage}");
            }
        }
    }
}


I referred to the Azure OpenAI Service REST API documentation for this implementation and the How-to Guide on Creating and Managing Compute Sessions in Azure.

Additionally, I referred to the How to Manage Compute Sessions for PromptFlow and How to Customize Session Base Image for PromptFlow.

Below is the code to create images given a prompt.
POST https://{endpoint}/openai/deployments/{deployment-id}/images/generations?api-version=2024-10-21

{
 "prompt": "In the style of WordArt, Microsoft Clippy wearing a cowboy hat.",
 "n": 1,
 "style": "natural",
 "quality": "standard"
}



